# IDE0006 warning and many others on new Cross Platform Xamarin app with a fresh install of Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2017

I just installed Visual Studio 2017 on a PC running Windows 10, and created a Cross Platform Xamarin app (Blank and PLC) called "trial". Right off the bat, the following warning came up in the Errors box:

```
IDE0006 - Error encountered while loading the project. Some project pfeatures, such as full solution alaysisis for the failed project and projects that depend on it, have been disabled.

To see what caused the issue, please try below.

1. Close Visual Studio
2. Open a Visual Studio Developer Command Prompt
3. Set environment variable "TraceDesignTime" to true (set TraceDesignTime=true)
4. Delete .vs directory/.suo file
5. Restart VS from the command prompt you set the environment variable (devenv)
6. Open the solution
7. Check 'C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Temp\\trial.Android_*.designtime.log' and look for the failed tasks (FAILED)
```

Since then, I've tried creating many other apps, all of which start with at least that warning, and usually more. Searching for the other errors yields no results - searching for the IDE0006 one yields [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38174145/ide0006-error-running-xamarin-android-project-in-visual-studio) and a few suggestions to update packages, but I tried all of them, including various combinations of updating/reinstalling/using previous versions of packages, deleting the "System.ObjectModel" reference, restarting, cleaning, and rebuilding, and the errors are still there. I even tried uninstalling and reinstalling Visual Studio, but nothing changed.

Weirder still, when I run my Android project despite the errors, nothing happens. On my first install of Visual Studio, an Android emulator popped up -
 the screen was completely black which I doubt is expected behavior but at least the emulator was there - but ever since the reinstall, nothing at all happens, and all errors and warnings just disappear from the Error box, so the box is totally empty (although the top bar still displays "1 Warnings"), and I can't get them to come back. I set up my Android project exactly as prescribed [here](https://university.xamarin.com/resources/win-setup).

I started to follow the 7 steps outlined in the error, but I couldn't find any ".vs" directory or ".suo" file, and then it occurred to me that I didn't know what I was doing and I didn't want to risk screwing up Visual Studio even further (I can't find any references to the 7 steps on Google and they also contain misspellings, so they feel outdated/sketchy). Anyone have any experience/insight on these steps?

Here are some of the other warnings that keep popping up - I assume/hope that all the warnings are caused by the same fundamental error, but I can't find any record of anyone else encountering any but the one above.

```
Cannot resolve Assembly or Windows Metadata file 'System.Runtime.dll'   trial.UWP   C:\Users\User\source\repos\trial\trial\trial.UWP\trial.UWP.csproj

Type universe cannot resolve assembly: System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=jf98hs8fsihso9. trial.UWP

Could not load assembly 'trial, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken='. Perhaps it doesn't exist in the Mono for Android profile?   trial.Android

The "ResolveLibraryProjectImports" task failed unexpectedly.
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load assembly 'trial, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken='. Perhaps it doesn't exist in the Mono for Android profile?
File name: 'trial.dll'
   at Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.Resolve(AssemblyNameReference reference, ReaderParameters parameters)
   at Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.Resolve(String fullName)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveLibraryProjectImports.Extract(DirectoryAssemblyResolver res, ICollection`1 jars, ICollection`1 resolvedResourceDirectories, ICollection`1 resolvedAssetDirectories, ICollection`1 resolvedEnvironments)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveLibraryProjectImports.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext() trial.Android
```

I've been tearing my hair out over this. I was really looking forward to learning Xamarin but I literally haven't been able to code a single line yet. What could be going on?? It's like my install is corrupted or something, but I don't see how that is possible, especially since I downloaded it twice, from the [official site](https://www.xamarin.com/download).

---

**UPDATE**

I tried the solution given [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/90844/xamarin-forms-obviously-broken), namely building the Android project, unloading it then reloading it. All my warnings disappeared when I built it, but when I unloaded it I got this single error (which has appeared sporadically before), which remained.

```
The referenced component 'System.ObjectModel' could not be found.
```

(I've already removed "System.ObjectModel" from the list of references, which worked once on that error, but since then it's recurred). When I ran the app, it said "There were deployment errors, would you like to continue?" like it always does, I clicked "yes", and once again nothing happened. The single warning remained, even when the build the Android project again.

---

**UPDATE 2**

I created a new project and uploaded it to Github to demonstrate the problem: https://github.com/joeymorano/newfailure

---

**UPDATE 3**

I  tried:

```
1.) Cleaning
2.) Deleting all `bin` and `obj` files 
3.) Rebuilding
```

but I still have errors. To be sure, I created a new project and tried the same steps, and three errors went away, but there's still the IDE0006 error. I uploaded that project too: https://github.com/joeymorano/stack

---

**UPDATE 4**

I still have the following errors this app: https://github.com/joeymorano/newfailure

```
Error   CS0103  The name 'InitializeComponent' does not exist in the current context


Warning     The referenced component 'System.ObjectModel' could not be found.
```

Here's the Build Diagnostics, with the build verbosity set to Normal (it was too long to post here so I made a Google doc - Warning, it really is ridiculously long): https://docs.google.com/document/d/1qUJDdjNNOBqhS_Sp9pvH6ipLx67l5fgskRX4ltluxM8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I think you have some issue with installation on android.... did you try to reinstall?   how you install VS, using vs installer?

Comment: @ShiwankaChathuranga I uninstalled and reinstalled. Yes, I downloaded the official version from https://www.xamarin.com/download and used the VS Installer to guide the installation process.

Comment: Could you please share a basic demo that can reproduce the problem through online repo ? It seems that your project configuration has some problem.

Comment: @YorkShen-MSFT You mean just post a copy of one of my failing apps?

Comment: Yeah, to make sure we are verifying the exact same thing you are using.

Comment: I found a same issue,  you could refer to : https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/90844/xamarin-forms-obviously-broken

Comment: @YorkShen-MSFT I uploaded it to Github and added a link to the question. Does that work? Also, that sounds like the exact problem I have. I tried the solution given, though, and three errors went away but I got a new one (update 2).

Answer (score 5):

Do the following steps :

- 1. Clean your solution
- 2. Delete the bin and obj folder
- 3. Reopen your Visual Studio and rebuild again.

I have test your project on my side, it works fine.

> The referenced component 'System.ObjectModel' could not be found.

This is just a warning, not an error. You can remove it from your `Xamarin.Android` project if you do not use `INotifyPropertyChanged` and `ICommand` within your `Xamarin.Android` project.

### Update :

Open  your  solution

When you deploy your `Xamarin.Android` project on emulator, you need to do some configuration. If you use a `arm` architecture emulator, it will very slow, it is recommended to use `x86` architecture emulator, for example :

[image]

When you use a `x86` architecture emulator, you need enable the [Hardware Acceleration](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/debug-on-emulator/android-sdk-emulator/1-hardware-acceleration/).

You could try using your `Xamarin.UWP` project, right click on your `Stack.UWP`, choose `Set as StartUp Project`,

[image]

Then deploy the `Stack.UWP` on your `Location Machine`. If this has no problem, I think you need to post the complete  `Xamarin.Android` deploy errors, so we could  help you pinpoint the problem.

---

### Update 2 :

Right click on your project solution, open the `Manage Nuget Packages for solution`, update the `Xamarin.Forms` package to the latest version. Then clean your solution, delete the `bin` & `obj` folder and restart you VS again.

Comment: Should I delete the bin and obj folders in all four projects? Or just Android?

Comment: @JoeMorano, delete them all.

Comment: I tried that solution but still had errors, and then I tried it on a brand new project, and that still had errors too. I uploaded the second project too. I never have any actual errors listed, but every time I try to run the app it says there are deploy errors, and nothing happens (when the emulator is supposed to appear).

Comment: When it tells you  there are deploy errors,  could you please share a [diagnostic build output](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/troubleshooting/troubleshooting/#Diagnostic_MSBuild_Output) ?

Comment: @JoeMorano, your project has no problem, I think there is something wrong with your other configuration.  Are you set your `Xamarin.Android` as a `Start project' ? Did you deploy your project on an emulator or a real device ?

Comment: Yes, Xamarin.Android is the StartUp Project. I've tried it both on an emulator and a real device.

Comment: @JoeMorano, could you please post the deploy errors ? You could see it in [diagnostic build output](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/troubleshooting/troubleshooting/#Diagnostic_MSBuild_Output).

Comment: @JoeMorano, I have update my answer, please check it.

Comment: For what it's worth, I'm able to compile fine and I frequently get a hang up every single time I try to deploy on the zipalign step on multiple development machines. I think it's an issue with Xamarin.Android and/or Visual Studio. This used to be a bug for a really long time, then an update fixed it, then an update brought it back. I cancel the build when it gets stuck on zipalign, then restart and it works the second time. It's very annoying but there is a workaround.

Comment: I also see the ''Some project features failed to load" if for example, I recently modify an AXML file then immediately try to build. The solution is to wait 10-15 seconds then build again. This happens on multiple machines. Visual Studio 2017 is very buggy with Xamarin.Android right now.

Comment: My apps still have warnings and sometimes errors right off the bat. I added the build diagnostics for my app.

Comment: @JoeMorano, I have update my answer, please check it.

Comment: I tried your Update 2, but the errors are still there. I really appreciate your efforts though, so I'm awarding you the bounty.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't my work, but I found something similar on GitHub. https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/17667

**From Pilchie**

I just took a look and I see these errors:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Warning IDE0006 Error encountered while loading the project. Some project features, such as full solution analysis for the failed project and projects that depend on it, have been disabled.   Monitoramentos      1   Active
Warning     The "XamlCTask" task could not be instantiated from "D:\KevinPi\Downloads\Monitoramentos\Monitoramentos\packages\Xamarin.Forms.2.3.3.193\build\portable-win+net45+wp80+win81+wpa81+MonoAndroid10+Xamarin.iOS10+xamarinmac20\Xamarin.Forms.Build.Tasks.dll". Could not load file or assembly 'Xamarin.Forms.Build.Tasks, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. Operation is not supported. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131515) Monitoramentos          
Warning     The "XamlCTask" task has been declared or used incorrectly, or failed during construction. Check the spelling of the task name and the assembly name.   Monitoramentos
```

After I deleted the packages\Xamarin.Forms.2.3.3.193\ and did a new restore from NuGet, things worked as expected. I suspect a file in the packages directory is corrupt somehow.

Comment: Where do you go to delete a package, and how do you do a new restore from NuGet?

Comment: nuGet: https://dotnet.myget.org/F/roslyn/api/v3/index.json - again - this isn't mine, just might help. There's probably a corrupted file that isn't deleted when the app is, that the app keeps referring back to. I really don't know that much, just trying to help.

Comment: @JoeMorano, right click your project solution, then you could click the `Restore Nuget Packages`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Close solution
2. Delete the 'package' folder in your solution directory
3. Open solution and built it to install nuget packages again.